# Find the area between the outer and inner loops of =2+3sin()

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, area, polar-coordinates

Find the area between the outer and inner loops of $=2+3\sin(\theta)$

[image]

So, firstly I integrated from $\arcsin(-2/3)$ to $\pi/2$ to find the half area of the outer loop.
Then, I integrated from $\arcsin(-2/3)$ to $3\pi/2$ to find the half area of the inner loop.

Area = (Half outer area - half inner area)*2

I got $17\pi/4$, but I'm not sure if it's right

Comment: First, I integrated from arccos(-2/3) to pi/2 to find the half area of the outer loop. Then, I integrated from arccos(-2/3) to 3pi/2 to find the half area of the inner loop. Afterwards, Area = (Half outer area - half inner area)*2 
I got 17pi/4, but I'm not sure if it's right

Comment: @Santeigspd graph you have attached is of $r=2+3\sin\theta$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840728/find-polar-area-inner-loop-r-12sin-theta?rq=1) is very similar, maybe it helps.

Comment: @Believer sorry, it is actually 2+3sin()

Comment: @Santeigspd I wrote answer with respect to $r=2+3\cos\theta$

Comment: @Believer thank you!

Comment: @Santeigspd use similar idea for the original one. If any doubt, let me know.

Comment: $17\pi/4$ is about 13.35. One can see from picture that area is greater than 16, because part excluded by inner loop is smaller than parts outer to square 4×4 formed by lines $x=-2$, $x=2$, $y=0$, $y=4$. So, answer $17\pi/4$ is incorrect

Comment: For half inner loop one need to integrate from $\pi+\arcsin(2/3)$ to $3\pi/2$ or from $-\pi/2$ to $\arcsin(-2/3)$